# Redirect URL with question mark and wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In .htaccess, how can I redirect all URLs like this

```
site.com/?author=X
```

(where X is any number)

to

```
site.com/theonlyauthor
```

(I've seen many posts about redirecting with either a question mark or with a wildcard, but not both.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the root folder of

```
http://example.com/
```

upload an `.htaccess` file, containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^author=
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/theonlyauthor? [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't quite work - it redirects to example.com/theonlyauthor/?author=X and therefore 404s.

Comment: Try it again, but this time add a final question mark at the end of the `Rewrite` (I have edited the post above to show this). This should rewrite the query as an empty query.

Comment: You're most welcome. And good practice for me - I need to remember that final question mark!